# Cannot find Windows 8 option in GRUB menu after installing 13.04

Tags: 13.04, grub2, windows-8

I've installed Ubuntu 13.04 in a separate partition of my hard drive which also has Windows 8 in another partition.  The problem is, GRUB menu is not showing windows 8 OS to boot into.

So if I want to boot into Windows then I must go into boot priority and change boot order.
What should I do to get windows 8 option in GRUB menu?

Also I cannot access other partitions of the hard drive where Windows is installed, similarly cannot access Ubuntu partition when using windows.

(I found similar question in this section but did not understand it as I'm new to this platform.)

Comment: Your Ubuntu partition will be formatted ext3 or ext4.  Windows does not understand them.  Also can you limit each question to one subject. It is OK to ask more than one question.

Comment: Is your Windows pre-installed with UEFI and you installed Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode. Then the only way you can dual boot is by going into UEFI/BIOS as they boot differently. You can use Boot-Repair to convert a BIOS install of Ubuntu to UEFI and then dual boot from grub menu. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

You will need to manually put the entry back into your grub file.  Edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg

In fact, Ubuntu has a nasty habit of changing your grub.cfg even for a minor header update to your existing kernel.  Though minor updates do not cause you to lose boot partition info (as apparently happened with your update to 13.X), the updates still change your default boot kernel, without asking or presenting an option to keep the grub.cfg the way it is/was.

For instance, I have a custom network driver, and I always end up with a networkless PC if I take the default grub config after a kernel header update.

Thus, be sure to SAVE your grub.cfg somewhere outside of the /boot partition. If you accept the kernel header updates, you can restore your grub.cfg to as it was before the updates, if you saved a copy of it somewhere beforehand.